# Equations solvable by LambertW

Tags: lambert-w, python

I am trying to implement equations solvable by `LambertW` in `python`, but I am unable to get the desired resources about how to solve such equations. I know what `LambertW` is,
but I want to know:

- How to determine whether an equation is solvable by `LambertW`.
- How to solve an equation by `LambertW`.
- Some references that explains its implementation so that it becomes easy for
  me to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to be covering all posible cases but, at least, any equation which can write as $$A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$$ has solutions in terms of Lambert function.

The solution(s) write $$x=-\frac DE+\frac CB\,W(t)\qquad \text{with}\qquad t=\frac B{CE}\,\exp\left(\frac{BD-AE}{CE}\right)$$

Lambert function is [implemented](http://pythonfiddle.com/lambert-w-function/) in Python

Comment: thanks @Claude. Could you please provide me with some references, that have such description about `LambertW` function

Comment: @Yathartha. You are welcome ! If you look at the Wikipedia page, you will notice that a lot of manipulations lead to something like what I wrote. If you search, there are so many applications of this beautiful function in many domains. https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf

Comment: yeah, I will have a look at the Wikipedia page.
It's weird but I don't know why I found the pdf a bit confusing and complex.
I was looking for a much simpler explanation.

Comment: The solution in this post is a generalization of the solution in the Wikipedia article, which is in the form $P^x=Dx+E$. The Wikipedia solution can be converted to the solution here, with $A=0, C=1, B=log(P)$.